# Dash bootstrap components not showing

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I wanted to have progress bar in my Django project but it is not showing on page. I have installed
django-dash and dash-bootstrap-components. Code:

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash("Progress", add_bootstrap_links=True)
app.layout = html.Div(dbc.Progress(value=100))
```

and template

```
{% load plotly_dash %}
<div class="{% plotly_class name="Progress" %}">
    {% plotly_app_bootstrap name="Progress" %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time figuring out why dash-bootstrap-components are not loaded on my Django dash app. I figured out the problem using simple steps available at :

https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrap.html#using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky to set up - you have to follow all of the installation steps. There is a [summary](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrap.html#using-bootstrap) in the project documentation:

- add the various settings from the configuration section of the project documentation, particularly the `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, `PLOTLY_COMPONENTS` and `MIDDLEWARE` ones.
- install django-bootstrap 4 with `pip install django-bootstrap4` and add `bootstrap4` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the project’s `settings.py` file
- make sure that the settings for serving static files are set correctly, particularly `STATIC_ROOT`, as described in the Django documentation
- use the `prepare_demo` script or perform the equivalent steps, particularly the `migrate` and `collectstatic` steps

Comment: what does prepare_demo script mean?Could you help me understand this @delsim

Comment: Its a configuration script for the demo that is part of the django-plotly-dash codebase. You can find the master version [here](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/master/prepare_demo) - essentially, it executes Django migrate and collectstatic steps.

Comment: I tried these basic steps already.still it doesn't display anything @delsim

Comment: @SriTest look at the server and also the debug console in a browser on the client - are there error messages and/or files not being served? If so then you need to address the cause of those errors. Once you can move past this, if the app still isn't rendering as desired, then try taking out bootstrap-specific parts until it does work, and then add them back one at a time to determine which step is causing the problem.

Comment: debug console I get the following error :DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://unpkg.com/dash-core-components@1.7.0/dash_core_components/dash_core_components.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE @delsim

Comment: I get the same error for multiple packages and the documentation doesn't say much in regards to how to handle this. guess I'll just import an iframe from a stand-alone dash app web server.